# better solution with cast in generic java

Tags: java, generics

Suppose I have the following code:

```
Object li = new Object(); 

// this causes a compiler warning   

ArrayList<String> lo = (ArrayList<String>)(li);
```

Okay, I have edited the question, sorry, I made a mistake, the point is, since it will cause a compile time warning when we cast to the target, whose target is a parameterized type, is there any better solution so that I can prevent the code from causing a compile time warning?

When dealing with arrays, we have Arrays.newInstance to replace the use of cast.

---

code from original question:

```
// List<String> is a superclass of ArrayList

List<String>      listOne =  new List<String>();

ArrayList<String> listTwo = (List<String>) listOne;
```

Comment: List<E> is interface ,not instance. ArrayList<E> implements to LiSt<E>

Comment: What is the compile time warning you get?

Comment: You won't accomplish anything by getting rid of the compiler warning:  A _ClassCastException_ will be thrown at runtime if you execute the above code.  You can't cast an Object to an ArrayList<String>.  That doesn't make sense.

Comment: All class extends to object ,so a class self is object cast is error.

Answer (score 1):

You can't instantiate a List, because [List is an interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

An [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is a **class** that *implements* the List **interface**.

You can do this:

```
List<String> listOne  =  new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> listTwo  =  listOne;
```

This is the correct approach when the code using *listOne* doesn't care what kind of List it is.

Here's an example that demonstrates why this is a good approach:

`List<String> someList = createList();`

Here *someList* is set to the return value of a method named *createList*.  In this situation we have no idea what kind of list *someList* is.  It could be an ArrayList, a Vector, a Stack, etc...  As long as *createList* returns an object that implements the List interface, the above code will work.  With this approach, the code in *createList* can be modified without affecting the code that calls it.

You can also do this:

```
ArrayList<String> listOne  =  new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> listTwo  =  listOne;
```

This is not as flexible, but it allows you to treat your lists specifically as ArrayLists.

Technically, you can do this, but it's not a good idea:

```
List<String>      listOne  =  new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> listTwo  =  (ArrayList<String>) listOne;
```

It's better to [program to an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface) by declaring a List and instantiating an ArrayList.

Here's an example that shows some benefits of programming to interfaces:

```
public static void testIt() {

    List someList;
    ArrayList anArrayList;

    /*
     *  all of these will work 
     */

    someList = createVectorAsList();
    printList(someList);

    someList = createStackAsList();
    printList(someList);

    someList = createArrayListAsList();
    printList(someList);

    // you CAN assign an ArrayList to a List

    someList = createArrayList();
    printList(someList);

    // you CAN treat an ArrayList as a List

    anArrayList = createArrayList();
    printList(anArrayList);


    /* 
     *  none of these work 
     */

    // you can NOT assign List to an ArrayList

    anArrayList = createStackAsList();
    anArrayList = createVectorAsList();

    // you can NOT pass anything but an ArrayList to printArrayList

    printArrayList(createStackAsList());
    printArrayList(createVectorAsList());
    printArrayList(createArrayListAsList());

}

/** Prints any List */

public void printList(List someList) {
    for (Object o : someList) {
        System.out.println(o.toString());
    }
}

/** Prints ArrayLists only */

public void printArrayList(ArrayList someList) {
    for (Object o : someList) {
        System.out.println(o.toString());
    }
}

public List createVectorAsList() {
    Vector v = new Vector();
    v.add("I am a vector element");
    return v;
}

public List createStackAsList() {
    Stack s = new Stack();
    s.add("I am a stack element");
    return s;
}

public List createArrayListAsList() {
    ArrayList ar = new ArrayList();
    ar.add("I am an array list element");
    return ar;
}

public ArrayList createArrayList() {
    ArrayList ar = new ArrayList();
    ar.add("My array is not returned as a list...");
    return ar;
}
```

Comment: okay, thanks for your correction, i have edited the question, could you help me find a better solution?

Comment: You **can** instantiate a `List`: You can do so anonymously.

Comment: @Bohemian - How? (I can't figure it out)

Comment: Using an [anonymous class](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm): `List<String> list = new List<String>() { /* implement all methods */ public boolean add(String e) { whatever } etc`. Well technically an anonymous class is an *implementation* of an interface, but there's no class *file* for it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in such a situation, you have two options. The first is to do an unchecked cast:

```
Object o = getObjectFromSomewhereMysterious();
List<String> lst = (List<String>)o; //compiler warning
```

This will cause the warning you mention - what it means is that, because of [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), 
at runtime the cast can only check to make sure `o` is a `List`, but not a `List<String>`. So for example if `o` is a `HashMap` the cast will fail immediately, but if it's a `List<Integer>` it won't fail... until some later time when you try to treat an element of `lst` like a `String`. This is known as ["polluting the heap"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_pollution):

```
//some later place in the code path - who knows, it could be miles away
String str = lst.get(0); //ClassCastException if lst isn't really a List<String>
```

As long as you can be sure that the cast is safe, you can suppress the compiler warning:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") //this is safe because blah blah blah
List<String> lst = (List<String>)o;
```

*Always* document why the warning can be suppressed - this helps to keep the code maintainable.

The second option is to play it safe:

```
List<?> lst = (List<?>)o;
```

This means `lst` is a `List` of *some unknown type*. It allows you to avoid the unchecked cast, but places restrictions on what you can do with `lst`:

```
lst.add("some string"); //compiler error
```

That statement is illegal since we don't know whether `lst` is allowed to hold `String`s. The best we can do is read from it, but even then elements are only typed as `Object`:

```
Object element = lst.get(0);
```